# How to get range data into VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, function, range

I am starting to learn `VBA` programming in Excel, so my question might be pretty basic.
All I am trying to do is:

1) Get my code to set some range (row or column)
2) Get my code to create an array with the values of that range

Imagine that I have some numbers in `column A, from A1 to A50`. If I select cell `F7` (`rng1` in the code below) and run the code, I would like to get the data `A1:A7` (`rng2`), `Z5` would give me `A1:A5` and so on.

The first thing I tried was this:

```
Sub getdata()

    Dim rng1 As Range   'This will be the selected cell
    Dim rng2 As Range   'This will contain the data I want to retrieve
    Dim data() As Variant  'And this will be the data

    ' Define the ranges
    Set rng1 = Selection
    Set rng2 = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(rng1.Row, 1))

    'Get data
    data = rng2.Value
    Stop

End Sub
```

Which for some reason creates a tree structure instead of a one-dimensional array.

I would like to work comfortably with the data, so I looked and found a workaround on the Internet by means of this procedure:

```
Sub SubValuesFromRange()
    Dim someRange As Range
    Dim someValues As Variant

    Set someRange = Selection

    With someRange
        If .Cells.Count = 1 Then
            ReDim someValues(1 To 1)
            someValues(1) = someRange.Value
        ElseIf .Rows.Count = 1 Then
            someValues = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(someRange.Value))
        ElseIf .Columns.Count = 1 Then
            someValues = Application.Transpose(someRange.Value)
        Else
            MsgBox "someRange is multi-dimensional"
        End If
    End With
    Stop
End Sub
```

This procedure itself works fine. If I select `A1:A5` and run it, it gets de data. If I try it with a row it works as well.

So I tried to create a function out of it, that I could use in my main procedure and that would be very useful for my future programms.

Here the code and the function:

```
Sub getdata()
    Dim rng1 As Range   'This will be the selected cell
    Dim rng2 As Range   'This will contain the data I want to retrieve
    Dim data() As Variant  'And this will be the data

    ' Define the ranges
    Set rng1 = Selection
    Set rng2 = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(rng1.Row, 1))

    'Get data, this time throug the function
    data = ValuesFromRange(rng2)
    Stop
End Sub

Function ValuesFromRange(someRange)
    Dim someValues As Variant
    With someRange
        If .Cells.Count = 1 Then
            ReDim someValues(1 To 1)
            someValues(1) = someRange.Value
        ElseIf .Rows.Count = 1 Then
            someValues = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(someRange.Value))
        ElseIf .Columns.Count = 1 Then
            someValues = Application.Transpose(someRange.Value)
        Else
            MsgBox "someRange is multi-dimensional"
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

And... I get an error:

> Number 13, type mismatch

Any idea why?

Is there may be a simpler way to get Excel data into `VBA`?

Comment: It seems like you never set `ValuesFromRange` to be anything functions return themselves, so instead of `someValues`, maybe replace it with `ValuesFromRange`

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: Solved. There were two issues. First, in the main code, data had to be defined as "data" instead of "data()". Second "someValues" had to be replaced by "ValuesFromRange" within the function. Thanks!